# getfloat, the floating point analog of getint

Tags: c, parsing, floating-point

> Write getfloat, the floating-point analog of getint. What types does getfloat return as its function value?

`gefloat` would also return an integer value.
Here is my solution:

```
int getfloat(double *pf) {
    int c, sign;
    double power;

    while(isspace(c = getch()))
        ;
    if(!isdigit(c) && c != EOF && c != '-' && c != '+' && c != '.') {
        ungetch(c); /* push the number back in buffer */
        return 0; /* not a valid number */
    }

    sign = (c == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    if(c == '-' || c == '+')
        c = getch();

    if(!isdigit(c) && c != '.') {
        ungetch(c);
        return 0; /* not a number */
    }

    for(*pf = 0.0; isdigit(c); c = getch())
        *pf = *pf * 10 + (c - '0');

    if(c == '.')
        c = getch();

    for(power = 1.0; isdigit(c); c = getch()) {
        *pf = *pf * 10 + (c - '0');
        power *= 10;
    }

    *pf *= sign;
    *pf /= power; /* moving the decimal point */

    if(c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return c; /* it actually returns the value of the charachter that caused the break of the second for */
}
```

I have changed the type of the parameter `*pf` to `double`, thus it will handle the floating point represenation of a number. The condition of the first `if-statement` was extended, such that it will not push back in to the buffer a decimal point.
The second `for` computes the decimal part of the number, storing the number of places that the decimal point should pe moved in the variable `power`. If there is no decimal part, `power` will have the value `1` - thus, nothing will change if I devide `*pf` by `power` when `power` is `1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It obviously does not handle `NAN` and `INF`.  Maybe outside code's goals.
2. Surprisingly does not handle exponential notation such as 1.23e+56.
3. `if(!isdigit(c) && c != '.') {` returns a `0` implying "not a number" and ungets the offending `c`.  But a potential `+` or `-` was all ready consumed and not available for alternative parsings.  Not sure best way to handle, but maybe consider that once a non-white-space `char` is irrevocable consumed, this function should not return a error signal and should set `*pf` to _something_like 0 or NAN.
4. Minor: The `*pf /= power;` approach fails with input such as 123.00000...(300+ zeros) as `power` or `*pf` already became INF.
5. This is a pedantic point: Once you get about 17 (depends on `double`) decimal digits, the addition of `(c - '0')` to `*pf * 10` becomes moot.  To get a more accurate significand, forming the number right-to-left has precision advantages.
6. The `return c;` could return `0` indicating "not a number" .  Recommend an alternative return value scheme.
7. `ungetch` is not in the C spec.  Consider `ungetc()`.
8. With `ungetc()` "If the value of c equals that of the macro EOF, the operation fails and the input stream is unchanged." thus negating the need for the `if(c != EOF)`.  Still not bad to have there.
9. The decimal point `.` is locale sensitive and could be `,` or something else.  Use locale sensitive routines to determine the current decimal point.
10. You are commended for for taking in `"-0"` and rendering `-0.0` rather than `0.0`.
11. [Edit] [IEEE_754-2008 Character_representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Character_representation) discusses the maximum number of non-zero leading digits to use when converting from text to a number.  `double` is often a IEEE_754 binary64, so a maximum number to use is 17+3.  This goes into point #3 above.  Its a bit deep on how this affects things, but I'll just note it for those who want to delve into a portable robust solution.